# Is there a way to resize child elements of a GridLayout so that they fit the screen?

Tags: java, android, layout

I have created a GridLayout with 6 rows and 6 columns and I want to fill it with ImageViews and TextViews. I placed the Views in the 6 columns, but they are too big for the screen. What is the best way to adjust them so that the GridLayout columns automatically adjust to the screen?

Here is the XML that I have so far (only the first row is filled here)

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:rowCount="6"
    android:columnCount="6">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:src="@drawable/number_placeholder" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:src="@drawable/sign_placeholder" 
       />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:src="@drawable/number_placeholder"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:src="@drawable/sign_placeholder"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:src="@drawable/sign_placeholder"
  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="TextView" 
    />

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **match_parent** instead **wrap_content** in your GridLayout:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:rowCount="6"
  android:columnCount="6">
```

And then experiment with the layout_width and layout_height of your image and text views until you have the desired result.